# Unknown column 'product_variation_order.quantity' in 'field list'"

Tags: mysql, sql

The above query gives me an error in the title, am I missing something?
Tables and columns exist 100%

```
                CREATE VIEW product_variation_stock_view AS
                SELECT
                    product_variations.product_id AS product_id,
                    product_variations.id AS product_variation_id,
                    COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) AS stock,
                    case when COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) > 0
                        then true
                        ELSE false
                    END in_stock
                FROM product_variations
                LEFT JOIN(
                    SELECT
                        stocks.product_variation_id AS id,
                        SUM(stocks.quantity) AS quantity
                    FROM stocks
                    GROUP BY stocks.product_variation_id
                ) AS stocks USING (id)
                LEFT JOIN(
                    SELECT
                        product_variation_order.product_variation_id AS id,
                        SUM(product_variation_order.quantity)
                    FROM product_variation_order
                    GROUP BY product_variation_order.product_variation_id
                ) AS product_variation_order USING(id)
                GROUP BY product_variations.id
```

Comment: The answer is in your question. Dou have a table called product_variation_order and does it contain the field quantity.

Comment: The product_variation_order sub-select doesn't return that _column_.

Comment: @jeff yes I do. like @jarih said "The sub-select doesn't return that column", meaning all I needed to do is: ````  SUM(product_variation_order.quantity) AS quantity  ````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have redefined the meaning of the table name `product_variation_order` by using it as an alias in your `LEFT JOIN` expression:

```
     LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT
                product_variation_order.product_variation_id AS id,
                SUM(product_variation_order.quantity)
            FROM product_variation_order
            GROUP BY product_variation_order.product_variation_id
        ) AS product_variation_order
```

and that table does not have a `quantity` field in it. Perhaps you meant to use an alias:

```
SUM(product_variation_order.quantity) AS quantity
```

within the subquery?

Comment: Ok, I'm blind :D

Comment: Will accept your answer in 9 minute. Thanks, mate, again

Comment: @DwayneWalsh no worries. Sometimes it just needs a fresh set of eyes.